# Contents of List(Of String) are not saved

Tags: vb.net, class

I am attempting to parse paragraphs such as the following...

```
Group 1.  Does this or does that. Or Sometimes this. Or that.  

Group 2.  I do lots of things. But not this. Or that.

Group 3.  I do this. I do that. Sometimes this. Sometimes that.
```

The "Group 1-3" are the org Names, and each following sentence separated by a period is a function.

Code:

```
Public Sub parseParagraphs(paragraphList As List(Of String))
    Dim listOfOrgs As New List(Of EAB_Org)
    Dim listOfFuntions As New List(Of String)

    Dim orgName As String

    For Each item In paragraphList
        listOfFuntions.Clear()
        Dim words As String() = item.Split(New Char() {"."c}) 'Splits on periods
        orgName = words(0) 'Sets the orgName
        For index As Integer = 1 To words.Count - 1 'rest of items in list are functions performed
            listOfFuntions.Add(words(index))
        Next
        Dim anOrg As New EAB_Org(orgName, listOfFuntions)

        listOfOrgs.Add(anOrg)
    Next
End Sub
```

EAB Class:

```
Public Class EAB_Org
    Dim orgName As String
    Dim listOfTasks As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New(theOrgName As String, theListOfTasks As List(Of String))
        orgName = theOrgName
        listOfTasks = theListOfTasks
    End Sub

    Public Function getOrgName()
        Return orgName
    End Function

    Public Function getListOfTasks()
        Return listOfTasks
    End Function
End Class
```

For some reason, when I print out the contents of `listOfOrgs`, all the org names are correct, but the functions are all of the same and always the last set of functions read in.

Code I use to print:

```
Public Sub writeExcel(listOfOrgs As List(Of EAB_Org))
    For Each anItem In listOfOrgs
        Console.WriteLine(anItem.getOrgName)
        For Each anotherItem In anItem.getListOfTasks
            Console.WriteLine(anotherItem)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Output Looks Like:

```
Group 1
I do this. I do that. Sometimes this. Sometimes that.

Group 2
I do this. I do that. Sometimes this. Sometimes that.

Group 3
I do this. I do that. Sometimes this. Sometimes that.
```

Comment: Your code seems OK. Where do you call the method `writeExcel` and which `List(Of EAB_Org)` do you pass as argument?

Comment: @matsnow i call `writeExcel` in the `parseParagraphs` sub, and I pass it the `listOfOrgs` list. I ended up getting frustrated and transferring some code to the `EAB` class and everything works now. I am still very curious about why this code wasn't working for me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the constructor for EAB_Org, `theListOfTasks` is just a pointer to `listOfFuntions` (which you keep modifying) in the `parseParagraphs` Sub. In the constructor, you will need to create a new List(Of String) and copy the values from `theListOfTasks` into it.

Change the constructor to the following:

```
Public Sub New(theOrgName As String, theListOfTasks As List(Of String))
    orgName = theOrgName
    listOfTasks = New List(Of String)
    For Each item As String In theListOfTasks
        listOfTasks.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```